# Rails won't find a method that I added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, schema

I created a migration and ran `rake db:migrate`, but it's saying it's not there. In my IDE, it doesnt give me an error but doesnt save it in the database either. It gave me the error on the production version on Heroku.

Schema

```
  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.text     "pros"
    t.text     "cons"
    t.string   "category"
  end
```

Form, View:https://hastebin.com/otisoqibon.js

```
  <div class="field">
    <p class="flow-text">Category</p>
    <%= f.text_field :category, :class => "grey lighten-2 autocomplete", :id => "autocomplete-input", %>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
 def new
    @review = Review.new
  end
```

Error

```
 - 2017-04-20T01:49:22.051420+00:00 app[web.1]:
   ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `category' for ):
 - 2017-04-20T01:49:22.051421+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:   </div>
 - 2017-04-20T01:49:22.051423+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <p class="flow-text">Category</p>
 - 2017-04-20T01:49:22.051422+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:   <div class="field">
   - 2017-04-20T01:49:22.051424+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:     <%= f.text_field :category, :id => "autocomplete-input", :class => "grey
   lighten-2 autocomplete" %>
   - 2017-04-20T01:49:22.051424+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:   </div>
   - 2017-04-20T01:49:22.051425+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <div class="field">
   - 2017-04-20T01:49:22.051426+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <p class="flow-text">Pros, Woof Woof</p><br>
```

Comment: hello, could you add full view text? Have you restarted the server after running a migration?

Comment: i restarted it but im still getting the error :/

Comment: Try `spring stop` before restarting it

Comment: in local environment check migration status by `rake db:migrate:status` and check wether it's status is **down**

Comment: Is this the whole log of the request? undefined method `category' for what, i cant see.

Comment: It was for the review. It was <#reviewnumbers> but didnt show up when i put it in. I also checked the status and it was all up

Comment: @bbousq, please post your `app/models/review.rb`

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's because you did't run your rake db:migrate task on heroku yet.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```